# Using script to modify text file

Tags: vbscript

So, I found the following script to modify a text file, but having trouble tweaking it for my purpose.

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = "c:\test\file.txt"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strLine,"ex3")> 0 Then
        strLine = Replace(strLine,"ex3","ex5")
    End If 
    WScript.Echo strLine
Loop
```

I have a plc program that I am converting and need to convert B3[3].5 to B3[43], but the values change. Basically, the original text is B3[x].y and I need B3[z], where z = (16 * x) + y. I am able to use "B3[" as my search parameter, but not sure how to manipulate the tail end of the word.

There are hundreds of instances of this throughout the program and a script would be fastest way to modify it.

Here's a sample of the text file. You can see values for B3 vary. The number in the brackets can be anything from 0 to 60 and the number after the period is only 0 to 15.

```
ROUTINE _3_INFEED ()
N:  XIC(I[3].2) OTE(O[23].15);
N:  XIC(B3[12].9) TON(T4[0], ?, ?);
N:  [ XIC(I[16].0) [ XIO(O[22].0) XIO(O[22].1) , XIC(B3[12].9) ] , XIC(B3[12].10) XIC(O[22].1) XIC(I[16].0) ] OTE(B3[12].9);
N:  XIC(I[16].0) ONS(B3[10].7) XIC(O[22].1) OTU(B3[12].10);
N:  XIO(I[16].0) ONS(B3[10].10) XIC(O[22].0) OTL(B3[12].10);
N:  XIO(I[16].7) [ XIO(I[16].9) , XIC(B3[14].13) ] [ XIC(B3[12].10) , XIO(I[16].7) , XIC(O[22].1) , XIC(B3[12].11) ] OTE(B3[12].11);
N:  XIO(I[16].7) ONS(B3[10].8) XIC(O[22].0) OTU(B3[12].10);
N:  XIC(I[16].7) ONS(B3[10].9) XIC(O[22].1) OTL(B3[12].10);
N:  [ XIC(I[18].3) [ XIC(B3[12].9) XIC(T4[0].DN) , XIC(B3[12].10) ] XIO(B3[12].11) , XIC(I[18].6) [ XIO(I[16].9) XIC(B3[12].11) XIO(B3[14].13) , XIC(B3[7].0) ] XIC(T4[2].DN) XIC(I[16].1) XIC(O[22].3) ] OTE(B3[7].0);
N:  XIO(I[16].9) TOF(T4[2], ?, ?);
N:  [ [ XIC(I[18].3) XIC(I[66].4) XIC(B3[7].0) , XIO(I[18].3) XIC(I[18].4) ] [ XIC(T4[2].DN) XIC(I[16].1) XIC(O[22].3) , XIC(I[16].7) ] , XIO(I[66].4) XIC(I[66].6) XIC(I[16].1) ] [ OTE(O[66].6) , OTE(O[22].0) ];
N:  [ XIO(I[18].3) XIC(I[18].5) , XIO(I[66].4) XIC(I[66].5) ] [ OTE(O[66].5) , OTE(O[22].1) ];
```

Comment: what does your algo have anything to do do with ex3 and ex5?

Comment: give me a bit, you should be able to do this

Comment: there is only 1 field in this file correct?

Comment: It was just an example I found on here to get me started. Sorry, not a programmer. Yes, it's just the B3 portions I want to modify

Comment: so the only thing per line is   B3[3].5   there is nothing else per line?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim x
    Dim y
    Dim templine
    Dim objFile
    Dim objFS
    Dim strLine As String
    objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile("c:\test\file.txt")
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine
        If InStr(strLine, "B3[") > 0 Then

            templine = strLine
            'find x
            'find y
            'x = Mid(strLine,Instr(strLine,"[",Instr(strLine,"]"))
            'fixed

            templine = Mid(templine, InStr(templine, "B3[") + 3)
            x = sLeft(templine, InStr(templine, "]") - 1)
            templine = Mid(templine, InStr(templine, "]") + 2)
            y = sLeft(templine, InStr(templine, ")") - 1)
            templine = Mid(templine, InStr(templine, ")") + 1)
            strLine = Replace(strLine, "B3[" & x & "]." & y, "B3[" & CStr((16 * x) + y) + "]")
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. When I run it, it says it needs a ')' at (12, 55). I thought it could be from the line defining x needing a 3rd bracket at the end, but then it threw out type mismatch for strLine.

Comment: Does not compile and mis-uses Mid(,,**len**).

Comment: im sorry i havent coded in vb6 for quite sometime, i do not have an IDE to see if the code is perfect.  you have to work with whats above, im not going to code it for you

Comment: @ekkehard.Horner .net doesnt care if you leave out the len, assumed vb6 did the same  actually, per msdn, len is optional Public Shared Function Mid( _
   ByVal str As String, _
   ByVal Start As Integer, _
   Optional ByVal Length As Integer _
) As String

Comment: @MichaelRudnerEvanchik - The question (and your code) is (about) VBScript. The fault of your code is that you **need** the length to 'cut' the numbers from the string. For the first number you can use the ], but there is no delimiter/separator for the second one. So your approach doesn't even work in theory.

Comment: @MichaelRudnerEvanchik I appreciate your help and I know it's close. I'm just not very good at this type of programming, but will keep trying to make it work. If you can see any errors in your code and let me know, I would appreciate it.Thanks

Comment: so the only thing per line is B3[3].5 there is nothing else per line?

Comment: Wish I could up vote you Michael, I don't have enough points or something.

Comment: no worries maybe who ever down voted will understand, but its just stackoverflow, not my life

Comment: I tried that new code and it said type mismatch at (15, 2). It caused an error at first instance of B3.

Comment: after seeing your data its a whole new ballgame, you have to loop the line as well as the lines

Comment: Still won't work. `y = Mid(strLine, InStr(strLine, ".") + 1)` finds the **first** dot, not the one after the B3[] you need. **DON'T POST/TRUST UNTESTED CODE**

Comment: i already conceeded @Ekkhard your code is correct but more confusing to the OP AFTER he gave me his actual data, its not going to work or the correct solution.

Comment: code above should work now that you showed input, i did ask twice if your values where the only data in each line.

Comment: Sorry Michael, it still has issues. Saying expect statement on line 10, the 2nd Do loop. I tried adding adding a "loop" line after the second loop and that didn't help. I do understand your logic better. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: no problem, just be mindful of showing the data you want to process your question and your code your trying.  because of this i had to change my code many times, and found this guy jeremy who is down voting ever answers im giving to other people just because of the grudge he had with this post

Comment: actually let me fix the answer yes the end loop is missing. then you can try it again

Comment: tested code in vb.net , you might have to change the syntax but i dont think so

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this should be solved with a regular expression (to find the part to change and its components) and its replace function (to do the computations and the replacement). Demo:

```
Option Explicit

Function f(sm, sx, sy, np, ss) ' match, group1, ..., pos, source
  f = "B[" & (16 * CLng(sx) + CLng(sy)) & "]"
End Function

Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Pattern = "B3\[(\d+)\]\.(\d+)"

Dim s : s = "whateverB3[3].5dontcare"
WScript.Echo s, r.Replace(s, GetRef("f"))
```

output:

```
cscript 30874914.vbs
whateverB3[3].5dontcare whateverB[53]dontcare
```

For theory/background, start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx#scripting12_topic1).

**Update wrt Michael's InStr() strategy:**

While you can use something like

```
Dim p : p = InStr(s, "B3[")
Dim x : x = CLng(Mid(s, p + 3, InStr(s,"]") - p - 3))
WScript.Echo x
```

to get the first number via InStr(), you can't specify where the second number ends; you need a RegExp to exploit the concept of "number/string of digits".

**Update wrt published data:**

(reading the data from a file and applying the replace globally)

```
Option Explicit

Function f(sm, sx, sy, np, ss) ' match, group1, ..., pos, source
  f = "B[" & (16 * CLng(sx) + CLng(sy)) & "]"
End Function

Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Global  = True
r.Pattern = "B3\[(\d+)\]\.(\d+)"

Dim s : s = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("30874914.txt").ReadAll()
WScript.Echo s
WScript.Echo "---------------"
WScript.Echo r.Replace(s, GetRef("f"))
```

output:

```
cscript 30874914.vbs
ROUTINE _3_INFEED ()
N:  XIC(I[3].2) OTE(O[23].15);
N:  XIC(B3[12].9) TON(T4[0], ?, ?);
N:  [ XIC(I[16].0) [ XIO(O[22].0) XIO(O[22].1) , XIC(B3[12].9) ] , XIC(B3[12].10) XIC(O[22].1) XIC(I[16].0) ]
OTE(B3[12].9);
N:  XIC(I[16].0) ONS(B3[10].7) XIC(O[22].1) OTU(B3[12].10);
N:  XIO(I[16].0) ONS(B3[10].10) XIC(O[22].0) OTL(B3[12].10);
N:  XIO(I[16].7) [ XIO(I[16].9) , XIC(B3[14].13) ] [ XIC(B3[12].10) , XIO(I[16].7) , XIC(O[22].1) , XIC(B3[12]
.11) ] OTE(B3[12].11);
N:  XIO(I[16].7) ONS(B3[10].8) XIC(O[22].0) OTU(B3[12].10);
N:  XIC(I[16].7) ONS(B3[10].9) XIC(O[22].1) OTL(B3[12].10);
N:  [ XIC(I[18].3) [ XIC(B3[12].9) XIC(T4[0].DN) , XIC(B3[12].10) ] XIO(B3[12].11) , XIC(I[18].6) [ XIO(I[16].
9) XIC(B3[12].11) XIO(B3[14].13) , XIC(B3[7].0) ] XIC(T4[2].DN) XIC(I[16].1) XIC(O[22].3) ] OTE(B3[7].0);
N:  XIO(I[16].9) TOF(T4[2], ?, ?);
N:  [ [ XIC(I[18].3) XIC(I[66].4) XIC(B3[7].0) , XIO(I[18].3) XIC(I[18].4) ] [ XIC(T4[2].DN) XIC(I[16].1) XIC(
O[22].3) , XIC(I[16].7) ] , XIO(I[66].4) XIC(I[66].6) XIC(I[16].1) ] [ OTE(O[66].6) , OTE(O[22].0) ];
N:  [ XIO(I[18].3) XIC(I[18].5) , XIO(I[66].4) XIC(I[66].5) ] [ OTE(O[66].5) , OTE(O[22].1) ];

---------------
ROUTINE _3_INFEED ()
N:  XIC(I[3].2) OTE(O[23].15);
N:  XIC(B[201]) TON(T4[0], ?, ?);
N:  [ XIC(I[16].0) [ XIO(O[22].0) XIO(O[22].1) , XIC(B[201]) ] , XIC(B[202]) XIC(O[22].1) XIC(I[16].0) ] OTE(B
[201]);
N:  XIC(I[16].0) ONS(B[167]) XIC(O[22].1) OTU(B[202]);
N:  XIO(I[16].0) ONS(B[170]) XIC(O[22].0) OTL(B[202]);
N:  XIO(I[16].7) [ XIO(I[16].9) , XIC(B[237]) ] [ XIC(B[202]) , XIO(I[16].7) , XIC(O[22].1) , XIC(B[203]) ] OT
E(B[203]);
N:  XIO(I[16].7) ONS(B[168]) XIC(O[22].0) OTU(B[202]);
N:  XIC(I[16].7) ONS(B[169]) XIC(O[22].1) OTL(B[202]);
N:  [ XIC(I[18].3) [ XIC(B[201]) XIC(T4[0].DN) , XIC(B[202]) ] XIO(B[203]) , XIC(I[18].6) [ XIO(I[16].9) XIC(B
[203]) XIO(B[237]) , XIC(B[112]) ] XIC(T4[2].DN) XIC(I[16].1) XIC(O[22].3) ] OTE(B[112]);
N:  XIO(I[16].9) TOF(T4[2], ?, ?);
N:  [ [ XIC(I[18].3) XIC(I[66].4) XIC(B[112]) , XIO(I[18].3) XIC(I[18].4) ] [ XIC(T4[2].DN) XIC(I[16].1) XIC(O
[22].3) , XIC(I[16].7) ] , XIO(I[66].4) XIC(I[66].6) XIC(I[16].1) ] [ OTE(O[66].6) , OTE(O[22].0) ];
N:  [ XIO(I[18].3) XIC(I[18].5) , XIO(I[66].4) XIC(I[66].5) ] [ OTE(O[66].5) , OTE(O[22].1) ];
```

Comment: Thank you as well for your input. I understand your logic, but not sure how to implement it into my vb script.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, you have to understand i could have written above as well, but if somebody is asking a question like this, you cant give him the rockstar answer.  but i wont down vote you like you did to me, just because i do not have a good ide handy and wrote free handed

Comment: it works perfectly now that you actually showed your input data.  Even though i asked for it before i  answered